Spring boot : is it possible to include auto configurations in Test classes?
I'm writing some Spring boot tests. When using @SpringBootTest, it works fine, I got all auto configurations classes from spring jars. But I don't want to load the whole application context from @SpringBootApplication
For example I'm testing spring batch layer. I would like to benefit from all spring batch autoconfiguration.
Here's my test class :
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BankBatchApplicationTests.TestConfig.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class BankBatchApplicationTests {

    @ComponentScan("com.example")
    static class TestConfig {

    }

But it seems my test class isn't picking up auto configuration from spring-batch. Obviously when I use @SpringBootTest it works fine
Another solution would be to use @SpringBootTest, picking up my main @SpringBootApplication Application class. But I don't want to include other configurations classes scanned like KafkaConfiguration etc...

checkout my answer here, if it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78320556/enableautoconfiguration-doesnt-work-with-webmvctest-why/78321138#78321138

Have you tried to exclude the auto-configuration classes that you don't need in your test?
